# SQL Query to retrieve below average score

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello I'm working on a system for primary school and im stuck on queries in database part. I would like to retrieve:

- Number of students below the average score
- Average mark for each student across all tests
- Average mark for each test

I'm not really good at queries and I couldn't work it out. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Below you can find my tables and test data

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
    (
    StudentID INT  auto_increment,
    ClassID VARCHAR(10),
    FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    LastName VARCHAR(25),
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    Gender VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, ClassID)
    );

    create table Subjects
    (
    SubjectID INT,
    SubjectName VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubjectID)
    );



    create table Grade
    (
    StudentID INT,
    SubjectID INT,
    ClassID VARCHAR(10),
    Grade DECIMAL(5,1),
    FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SubjectID) REFERENCES Subjects(SubjectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Student(ClassID)
    );
```

Test data:

```
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, ClassID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender)
VALUES ('', '01', 'John', 'Smith', '15/01/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Michael', 'Black', '15/03/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Dennis', 'White', '07/08/1999', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Emy', 'Blue', '10/04/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Joe', 'Yellow', '09/05/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Aaren', 'Jackson', '09/009/1999', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Marta', 'Harris', '30/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Laura', 'Lewis', '09/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Michael', 'Jackson', '01/01/2000', 'Male'),

('', '02', 'Piotr', 'Kowalski', '15/01/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Harris', 'Bialy', '15/03/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Porter', 'Czarny', '07/08/1999', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Maciek', 'Blue', '10/04/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Mateusz', 'Yellow', '09/05/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Aaren', 'Jackson', '09/009/1999', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Marta', 'Harris', '30/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Laura', 'Lewis', '09/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Chaytan', 'Jackson', '01/01/2000', 'Male');


INSERT INTO Subjects (SubjectID, SubjectName)
VALUES ('01', 'English'),
('02', 'Mathematics'),
('03', 'Science'),
('04', 'Geography'),
('05', 'IT'),
('06', 'History');

INSERT INTO Grade (StudentID, SubjectID, ClassID, Grade)
VALUES ('1', '2', '01', '60.5'),
('2', '2', '01', '70.0'),
('3', '2', '01', '40.0'),
('4', '2', '01', '33.5'),
('5', '2', '01', '90.0'),
('6', '2', '01', '77.5'),
('7', '2', '01', '89.0'),
('8', '2', '01', '74.0'),
('9', '2', '01', '66.5'),

('10', '2', '02', '30.5'),
('11', '2', '02', '50.0'),
('12', '2', '02', '30.0'),
('13', '2', '02', '73.5'),
('14', '2', '02', '70.0'),
('15', '2', '02', '57.5'),
('16', '2', '02', '69.0'),
('17', '2', '02', '34.0'),
('18', '2', '02', '76.5'),

('1', '1', '01', '65.5'),
('2', '1', '01', '73.0'),
('3', '1', '01', '41.0'),
('4', '1', '01', '39.5'),
('5', '1', '01', '96.0'),
('6', '1', '01', '70.5'),
('7', '1', '01', '80.0'),
('8', '1', '01', '74.0'),
('9', '1', '01', '64.5'),

('10', '1', '02', '55.5'),
('11', '1', '02', '43.0'),
('12', '1', '02', '61.0'),
('13', '1', '02', '49.5'),
('14', '1', '02', '76.0'),
('15', '1', '02', '80.5'),
('16', '1', '02', '99.0'),
('17', '1', '02', '100.0'),
('18', '1', '02', '55.5');
```

Comment: And where is your tried query ?

Comment: @Mihai yes totally agree with you its a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you have all your homework in one fiddle send it to your teacher :D [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a4e/16)

```
SELECT Student.StudentID, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, Grade.Grade, Subjects.SubjectName
FROM Student INNER JOIN Grade ON Grade.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects ON Grade.SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID
WHERE Grade.Grade<50;

SELECT Student.StudentID, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, AVG(Grade.Grade) AS Average 
FROM Student INNER JOIN Grade ON Grade.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
GROUP BY Grade.StudentID;

SELECT Subjects.SubjectID, Subjects.SubjectName, AVG(Grade.Grade) AS Average 
FROM Subjects INNER JOIN Grade ON Grade.SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID 
GROUP BY Grade.SubjectID;
```

Comment: Its not a homework. Do you know any good website where I can learn more about queries? Thanks

Comment: coding is all about practice / test / fix, the web is full of good examples, you just have to check them out test them see why they fail fix and learn. If you go on asking on SO and copying and pasting you'll never learn sql. just don't say I don't know

Comment: By the way your query to return below average returns all results below 50 which is not the average

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my first tries :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Grade WHERE Grade <= AVG(Grade);
SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM Grade GROUP BY StudentID;
SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM Grade GROUP BY SubjectID;
```

Some adaptations to your specific case might be necessary. By the way, next time your use Stack Overflow, post your attempts. Efforts are greatly appreciated here, and will help you improve beyond this particular case. Plus, copy/paste won't make you capable after graduation.

About `GROUP BY` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html, and `AVG` : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm.

Comment: Sorry about not posting my attempts. However my phpMyAdmin does not provide history of attempts. Next time i'll make sure I post them